# Printing an array of String arrays in a TableModel

Tags: java, arrays

I get a `String[][]` from a *webservice* and I want to populate a `defaultTableModel` with the result.

The `String[][]` will contain objects so I thought about going for a builder.

```
  private void buildTableModel(String[][] aSa, faultTableModel dtm) {
    }
```

I can´t figure this out.

Comment: What did you try yet? Some more Informations would be good.

Comment: Please post specific issue you are facing.

Comment: So, presumably, each element in the outer array is the row, and each element of the inner array is the columns...

Comment: I tried two for loops @MadProgrammer yes thats exactly it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to append data to an existing DefaultTableModel then you can use the `addRow(...)` method to copy each row of data to the model:

```
for (int i = 0; i < aSa.length; i++)
    dtm.addRow(aSa[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TableFill {

    public void fillModel(DefaultTableModel model, String[][] asa) {
        model.setRowCount(0);
        model.setColumnCount(0);
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(asa[0]);

        for(int i = 1; i < asa.length; i++){
            model.addRow(asa[i]);
        }

    }
}
```